# Animation of tube with fixed height

Tags: graphics3d, animation

the problem is following:
my task is to make an animation: tube changes its radius but doesn't change its height.
With command

```
Animate[Graphics3D[{CapForm["Square"], Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}}, r]}], 
        {r, 10^(-9), 1}, AnimationRunning -> False]`
```

It changes both radius and length. How to make the fixed length?

Comment: `Cap` is expanding too. Use `CapForm[None]`. You can use `Cylinder` too and don't worry about `CapForm`. And hi, welcome to Mathematica SE. :)

Comment: Hi :) But this didn't help :(

Comment: Ah I forgot, fix the `PlotRange` otherwise it will adjust and make an illusion. `PlotRange->2` for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the answer is:

- Fix [`PlotRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotRange.html) otherwise box will be scaled to fit the `Tube` and it creates an illusion of changing height.

[image]

- Use different [`CapForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CapForm.html) because `"Square"` creates excess (**edit**) which is proportional to the radius of basis! (**Thanks @Nasser**)

Well, not obvious but seems logical, "square" referrs to that.

[image]

Take a look here:

```
Graphics3D[{
                     Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}, 1],
  CapForm["Square"], Tube[{{2, 2, 0}, {2, 2, 2}}, 1],
  CapForm[None],     Tube[{{4, 4, 0}, {4, 4, 2}}, 1],
  CapForm["Butt"],   Tube[{{6, 6, 0}, {6, 6, 2}}, 1],
                     Cylinder[{{8, 8, 0}, {8, 8, 2}}, 1]
  }, Axes -> {0, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for antialiasing ;)

Comment: Ah, so that is why I could not make it work with PlotRange, I was using `CapForm["Square"]` as posted. So, with `CapForm["Square"]` there is no solution? Is this then a bug? or a feature?

Comment: @Nasser This is absolutely a feature and is how it is described in the docs. I was looking at this question earlier but ultimately did not answer it because to really answer the question you have to write a function that decreases the distance between the points as the radius grows. But this seems to be all that was required to fix the OP's problem so all's good I suppose.I thought he required that capform since he has specified it.

Comment: @Nasser and Pickett oh I've missed that. Well use `"Butt"`, it is not obvious that `Square` will show such behaviour but it seems logical that then it's cap height is scaled proportionally to radius.